# Selection of pupils under R' Gamliel in Berakhot 28a

Tags: history, beit-din-court, sanhedrin

> "תָּנָא אוֹתוֹ הַיּוֹם, סִלְּקוּהוּ לְשׁוֹמֵר הַפֶּתַח וְנִתְּנָה לָהֶם רְשׁוּת לַתַּלְמִידִים לִיכָּנֵס. שֶׁהָיָה רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל מַכְרִיז וְאוֹמֵר: כׇּל תַּלְמִיד שֶׁאֵין תּוֹכוֹ כְּבָרוֹ, לֹא יִכָּנֵס לְבֵית הַמִּדְרָשׁ. [Berakhot.28a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.28a.2?lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en)

R' Gamliel (the Younger?) instituted guards at the entrance of a Beis Midrash to prevent unworthy pupils from entering and studying the Torah.

1. What was his Halachic reasoning for limiting Torah study?
2. How did the guard make the selection in fact? What tests show that pupils' ברו disagree with their תוכו?
3. How does it relate to the guard in the story of Hillel that took money for entering the study hall?

Comment: Isn't this Rabban Gamliel the Younger?

Comment: @Harel13 Right, very probable.

Comment: Why very probable? All the other chachamim in the story are from after the churban.

Answer (score 1):

According to Yalkhut Meam Loez on Pirkei Avot 1:1, Rabban Gamliel did not want to teach students whose motives for learning Torah were not entirely Le Shem Shamayim. In his own words, he stated (David N. Barocas, Ladino _English translator for this volume of Meam Loez quoting Rabbi Yitzchak Magriso), "Any student whose mouth and heart are not equally sincere shall not be admitted to the academy". Rabbi Magriso explains, "His argument was that if a person's motives in studying Torah are not absolutely pure, then it is better for him not to study at all"

Comment: And where do we see this in Halacha? Did Moses choose pupils? Did Hillel? Why then all of sudden?

Comment: Indeed the same work goes on to say "Rather, the sages should emulate what Rabbi Elazar did when he became head of the academy. He allowed all students to enroll in the academy, arguing that even if a student has ulterior motives, the study of Torah will improve hin"

Comment: No, wait, I presume that every decision of R"G was Halachic. This was the question: what's the Halachic support for his decree?